# Селекторы nth-child и их работа с одинаковыми блоками

Tags: css-selectors, toggle

Не могу заставить работать вторую ссылку на раскрытия блока. Идентификаторы и идентичность блока необходима, так как их создает модуль в opencarte
Поэтому добраться до второго блока могу только через селекторы. Но ни в какую не могу заставить работать второй блок. Что я делаю не та?

```css
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input {display:none;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input + label + .spoiler_body, div.spoiler input + label + .spoiler_body{display:none;}
div.spoiler input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
      ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
    ВТОРОЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input {display:none;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input + label + .spoiler_body, div.spoiler input + label + .spoiler_body{display:none;}
div.spoiler input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
      ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_2">
  <label for="spoilerid_2">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
    ВТОРОЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
```

У тебя одинаковый id. Это противоречит спецификации и здравому смыслу. Вот так всё работает. Если тебе модуль добавляет одинаковый айдишник то это не очень правильный модуль.

Ну т.е. при твоей разметке ты на второй инпут вешаешь действие "открыть первый блок с таким айдишником" и он открывает первый элемент с id `spoilerid_1`

Но можно перебить поведение с помощью JS...

```js
$("label").click(function() {
     $(this).next(".spoiler_body").toggle();
     return false;
});
```

```css
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input {display:none;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input + label + .spoiler_body, div.spoiler input + label + .spoiler_body{display:none;}
div.spoiler input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
      ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
    ВТОРОЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я знаю что должен быть разный ID. Но есть модуль для Opencart, называется Simple простая регистрация. У него блок корзины, если в нескольких шагах используется, то просто дублируется со всеми ID

Comment: @Владимир Тытыкало так быть не должно. У тебя проблема в том, что ты пытаешься писать костыли к невалидному коду.

Comment: @Владимир Тытыкало я не уверен, но по моему ты никак не перебьешь в css атрибут `for`

Comment: Выходит что да. Уже даже пробовал #open_promo_<?php echo gettimeofday()['sec']?> вот такой id чтобы создавался. Но снова все та же проблема мать ее, всегда на странице есть два блока с корзиной товаров, которые полностью идентичны между собой со всеми айди. Просто один блок получает свойство display none

Comment: @ВладимирТытыкало дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input {display:none;}*/
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input + label + .spoiler_body, div.spoiler input + label + .spoiler_body{display:none;}
div.spoiler input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
div.spoiler:nth-child(2) input:checked + label + .spoiler_body {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
      ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spoiler">
  <input type="checkbox" id="spoilerid_1">
  <label for="spoilerid_1">Кнопка просмотреть видео</label>
  <div class="spoiler_body">
    ВТОРОЙ БЛОК
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: И оно работает?)

Comment: Нет. Я думал что можно как то добраться селекторами в одинаковым блокам с одним id, но увы никак( А id одинаковые создает модуль, так что исправить никак